# Can't get includeCollapsedDocs of the Field Collapsing feature to work in Solr 4

Tags: solr, fieldcollapsing

#### Problem

(Using Solr 4.3.0) I can't seem to get the includeCollapsedDocs parameter of Field Collapsing feature to work. Has this feature been dropped? I've only found a few mentions of it [here](http://blog.trifork.com/2009/10/20/result-grouping-field-collapsing-with-solr/) and [there](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-236).

#### Use case

I have indexed versioned documents so that each version is a separate document. So I use the field collapsing feature to group the versions together. But doing so I will have lost the unique meta data of each version. For example I need to be able to list the dates of each version when I display it. So I'm thinking that 'includeCollapsedDocs' would allow me to have both the groups and the documents with the meta data.

Answer (score 1):

The parameter to set to get the collapsed documents to show is 'group.limit'. So instead of setting 'collapse.includeCollapsedDocs.fl=*' I set 'group.limit=10'.

I need to read [the documentation](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing#Request_Parameters) more carefully.